# How to install/convert non-Python packages (.tar.bz2) to Anaconda packages?

Tags: python, anaconda, package, conda, miniconda

I need to convert some non-Python packages that are in the .tar.bz2 format to Anaconda/miniConda .egg files and install them. For this I would need a bld.bat file for Windows. Is there any place on the internet where I can find some examples to do this.

Maybe it is possible to write a .py Python script to do this as well. The .tar files are present online and I need to download and install those automatically using the script.

Answer (score 1):

With conda-build you can build non-Python packages the same way that you build Python packages. Sourcing from a tarball is supported.

Here is the documentation for conda-build with several tutorials and example recipes:

- https://conda.io/docs/building/build.html
- https://python-packaging-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. There was another tutorial linked here originally, but it got outdated, and it was removed. This new tutorial is the closest useful replacements resource for the original.

Comment: the link is dead

Comment: your first link is dead this time